# Como atribuir valores aos botões do Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap (como fazer a barra de menus atribuindo valores aos botões..ex.: Eu criei o botão "Início", como eu posso atribuir um valor ao mesmo para quando eu acessá-lo eu ir para a página do botão início...)

Comment: Pode explicar melhor a sua pergunta? está pouco clara.

Comment: Assim? `<a href="inicio.html" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Início</a>`

Answer (score 1):

As classes `btn` e `btn-*` podem ser usadas tanto em *buttons* (`<button>`) como *links* (`<a>`):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="botao">Botão</button>

<a href="https://www.google.com.br/" class="btn btn-primary">Link</a>
```

Se usar o `<button>` você tem que usar Javascript/jQuery para mudar a localização como explicou o @pnet.

Veja aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/B8L77/

Você pode ver a [documentação oficial sobre botões aqui](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar por exemplo:

`<a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Inicio</button></a>`

Você também pode ver exemplos de utilização de links e botões aqui por exemplo

`http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar`

Outro modo e utilizando javascript ou jquery e onclicked.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode também criar uma função em jquery que chame a sua página e no botão fazer a chamada dessa função assim:

Jquery:

```
function chamaInicio(){
   $(window.document.location).attr('href','url_da_sua_pagina_completo_aqui');
}
```

E aqui a chamada no seu botão

```
<input id="btnChamaInicio" type="button" class="btn btn-success col-md-1" value="Inicio" onclick=" return chamaInicio();" />
```

Testa e posta o resultado.